# Allow editing in a sheet, but protect it from Sorting

Tags: sorting

I have a sheet that is unprotected so that users can enter information in every field, but I need to protect the sheet from being sorted.  Sorting seems to screw up the formulas and links that are in the sheet.  I have seen a lot of help on how to protect the sheet but allow sorting, but not my problem which is the opposite of that.

It seems like it should be pretty straightforward; here's what I have now:

```
Sub ProtectRevHistory()

Worksheets("Revision History").Protect Contents:=False, AllowSorting:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

I don't get any errors with this, but it doesn't protect the Sorting.  Is that even possible to do?

Ultimately, if I can get it working, I would like to run it from the `Workbook_Open()` event but when I placed this code in the ThisWorkbook object, it asks me for a password on open, even though I left the Password parameter off.  Just hitting enter for the password gives me an error and also doesn't protect the Sorting.

Comment: @tunaki I can't believe you took the time to edit my personal comments that amount to "thanks for your help" out of this question 2 years after I posted it and after I posted the solution as well. Get a life man.

Answer (score 0):

So I broke down and used the macro editor to see if that would help me figure this out and I did get it working.  After that, I was able to put it in the Workbook Open event so that it runs on open.  Here's what it looks like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Sheets("Revision History").Protect Password:="StrongPasswordHere", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
    :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:= _
    True


End Sub
```

Maybe there is something about the parameters that I don't fully understand that makes it work when all of them are listed.  I'm not sure.  But at least this is out there now for anyone else who needs it!  The nice thing about it is that all of the Sorting functions on the Data tab are greyed out.  And if you try to sort in the Filter, it doesn't work either.  Success!!